# Added Link To Image, Only Partially Clickable HTML

Tags: html, image, hyperlink

I needed to turn my image into a hyperlink, so I wrapped the  tag around it. For some reason, only the bottom part of the image is clickable for the hyperlink. The rest of the image won't do anything.
This is my code:
`<a href="link-here"><img src="image-here"></a>`

Comment: Without further contex of where the image is positioned on the page, it's hard to determine the cause. Your clickable area could be blocked by another element that has its padding interfering with the image. If your image is contained in a block that is using a `position` value such as absolute or fixed, it could be bumping into another element so you could try repostioning it. Without further context, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

change width or height may be that is the problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).